# How do you reuse a partial view with setting different ids

Tags: asp.net-mvc, selector, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a partial view with a dropdown in it.  the code looks like this:

```
 <%=Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.Exercises, new SelectList(Model.Exercises, "Id", "Name", Model.SelectedExercise), new { @id = "exerciseDropdown", @class = "autoComplete" })%>
```

The issue is that I want to reuse this partial view in multiple places but I want to have a different id assigned to the control (instead of exerciseDropdown always) but on the outside I only have this:

```
 <% Html.RenderPartial("ExerciseList", Model); %>
```

Is there anyway to pass in an id into a partial view?
Is there a standard way to inject the ids into a partial view?

Right now I am doing things like this:

```
 <% Html.RenderPartial("ExerciseList", Model); %>
 <% Html.RenderPartial("ExerciseList2", Model); %>
```

where ExerciseList and ExerciseList2 are identical but with different ids but I am sure there is a better way.

Comment: Do you need them to have IDs, or just names local to the form they're in?

Comment: @Nick Craver - i think i need ids as i want jquery code to capture the click event for some processing

Comment: @oo - Can you post the jQuery code you're running...I'm pretty sure we can solve this by not needing the IDs :)

Comment: @Nick Craver - nothing fancy just something like "capture change event and do some ajax call " - $('#exerciseDropdown').change(function() {

Comment: @oo - Are you using the ID other than for the event binding? If not you could just use a class, which doesn't need to be unique (and only have 1 copy of the jQuery code)

Comment: @Nick Craver - but if i use a class then i wont know which actual dropdown is being clicked (assuming i have multiple ones on the page).  each dropdown should do a different thing when being clicked.

Comment: @oo - Can you explain a bit more, how should it act differently?  Usually you can approach this by finding things relative via jQuery

Comment: @Nick Craver - one dropdown should fire off an ajax query.  another dropdown should simply append some html to a table.  completely different uses just happens to be the same list needed in two places on the same page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you are using the same model to do both partial views.  I see two options for setting this up.

1. Like Nick said above, use a partial class and add the dropDownID property to your model.

**Warning Pseudo VB Code ahead

```
Partial Public Class Exercise
Dim _ddID as string

Public Property DropDownID as string
    Get
        Return _ddID
    End Get
    Set(byval value as string)
        _ddID = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Then in your controller:

```
Function Index() as ActionResult
    Exercise = getExercise() 'call to get your exercise model'
    Exercise.DropDownID = "DropDownID1"
    Return View(Exercise)
End Function
```

View:

```
 <%=Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.Exercises, new SelectList(Model.Exercises, "Id", "Name", Model.SelectedExercise), new { @id = model.DropDownID, @class = "autoComplete" })%>
```

Option 2:  Set in your ViewData dictionary

Controller:

```
Function Index() as ActionResult
    Exercise = getExercise() 'call to get your exercise model'
    ViewData("ExerciseID") = "DropDownID1"
    Return View(Exercise)
End Function
```

Call Partial View:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("ExerciseList", Model, ViewData); %>
```

View:

```
 <%=Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.Exercises, new SelectList(Model.Exercises, "Id", "Name", Model.SelectedExercise), new { @id = ViewData("ExerciseID"), @class = "autoComplete" })%>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just include the id you want to use in the model.

Comment: @NickLarsen - can you clarify with an example here?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I wanted different IDs because jQuery calendar was failing to write date to the required input field. Instead, it was writing date into the first field with the same ID.

So, I wasn't really concerned with the ID. So used something like this-

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DueDate, new Dictionary<string, Object> { { "class", "datepicker" }, { "id", Guid.NewGuid().ToString() } })
```